# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos pruebas siguientes: w.isupper () y not w.islower ()?

Tags: python

Acabo de sumergirme en la documentación de Python para responder a esta pregunta

> Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos pruebas siguientes: `w.isupper()` y `not w.islower()`

Para mí, la diferencia es que, en términos matemáticos, `w.isupper ()` significa

```
                                ∀x ∈ w, x∈ Upper
```

`not w.islower ()` significa

```
                                ∃ x ∈ w, x ∉ Lower
```

No sé si es suficiente para que todos digan que es diferente, es [teoría de cojuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_conjuntos) y, a veces, realmente necesito tiempo para resolverlo.
Además, puede haber otras razones computacionales o pitónicas que no conozco

Esta pregunta es del capítulo 1 de Natural Language Processing with Python

Comment: la primera es si todos son upper la segunda es si NO todos son lower

Comment: No solo eso. Mira: `"?".isupper()` y `"?".islower()` son ambos `False`.

Comment: ["The method isupper() checks whether all the case-based characters (**letters**) of the string are uppercase."](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isupper.htm) énfasis en **todos** y **letras**

Comment: dicho de otra manera: para `isupper()` si hay letras tienen que ser todas mayúsculas, para `islower()` si hay letras tienen que ser todas minúsculas. Ambas funciones ignoran símbolos y espacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visto como teoría de conjuntos, te falta un ingrediente más para comprenderlo, y es que, si bien es cierto que:

```
 Upper ∩ Lower = ∅
```

(es decir, no hay letras que sean a la vez mayúsculas y minúsculas), ocurre que:

```
 Upper ∪ Lower ≠ E
```

siendo E el conjunto de todos los caracteres. O lo que es lo mismo, `Upper` y `Lower` no son complementarios.

Es decir, hay caracteres que no son ni mayúsculas ni minúsculas, como por ejemplo el carácter `"?"` entre muchos otros (todos los signos de puntuación, por ejemplo).

Así que considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
 w="?"
```

el resultado de `not w.islower()` sería `True`, <s>ya que existe un carácter en ella (`x="?"`) tal que `x ∉ Lower`</s>. **Actualización** No es esta la razón, véase más abajo.

Sin embargo  `w.isupper()` sería `False`, ya que ninguno de sus caracteres está en `Upper`. Por tanto en este ejemplo `w.isupper()` es diferente a `not w.islower()`, con lo que se demuestra que no son equivalentes.

### Actualización

Mirando la documentación de Python veo que la cosa es un poco más complicada de lo que pensábamos. Ya que el tema de los alfabetos es mucho más que el código ASCII, y Python soporta Unicode, hay que ser muy puntilloso con qué significa exactamente ser mayúscula o minúscula.

Hay caracteres que no son ni lo uno ni lo otro, como hemos visto, y quizás Unicode contenga caracteres que sean a la vez mayúscula y minúscula.

La documentación de python dice:

> **str.isupper()**
>     Return true if all cased characters [4] in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.
>
> **str.islower()**. 
>   Return true if all cased characters [4] in the string are lowercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.

Y la nota al pie [4] dice:

> Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).

Así que, traduciendo esto a lenguaje de conjuntos tenemos que:

- `Cased` es el conjunto de los caracteres que pueden ser mayuscula o minúscula o "Título", es decir: `Cased = Upper ∪ Lower ∪ Title` (no se deduce de ahi que `Upper` y `Lower` sean disjuntos).
- `Upper` es un subconjunto de `Cased` contienendo caracteres mayúscula.
- `Lower` es otro subconjunto de `Cased` conteniendo caracteres minúscula.
- `Title` es otro subconjunto de `Cased` conteniendo caracteres compuestos por una pareja de dos, siendo el primero mayúscula. ASCII no tiene ningún carácter en esta categoría, pero Unicode sí. Por ejemplo `"ǈ"`.
- `w.isupper()` equivale a:

  ```
  (w ∩ Cased ≠ ∅) and (∀x ∈ (w ∩ Cased), x ∈ Upper)
  ```
- `w.islower()` equivale a:

  ```
  (w ∩ Cased ≠ ∅) and (∀x ∈ (w ∩ Cased), x ∈ Lower)
  ```
- Por tanto, finalmente, `not w.islower()` equivale a:

  ```
  (w ∩ Cased = ∅) or (∃x ∈ (w ∩ Cased), x ∉ Lower)
  ```

El detalle de incluir `Cased` y que deba haber al menos un elemento perteneciente a `Cased` es relevante, porque resulta que si bien `w="?"` nos da `w.islower() == False`, en cambio `w="a?"` nos da `w.islower() == True`.

> El primer caso da `False` porque la cadena no contiene ningún caracter en `Cased`.
>
> El segundo da `True` porque, quedándose sólo con los caracteres que están en `Cased`, todos ellos son Lower.

Dicho de otra forma, para verificar si una cadena es `lower()` se ignoran en principio todos los caracteres de la cadena que no sean letras (estrictamente hablando, que no pertenezcan a `Cased`). Pero si resulta que no tiene ninguna letra, entonces evalúa como `False`. Lo mismo se aplica a `upper()`.

Interesante!

Comment: Entonces, ¿la única diferencia entre los dos es sobre los caracteres en string no son letras?

Comment: Puede ser un detalle, pero es muy interesante

Comment: @Marine1 Mira la última actualización que acabo de hacer. La cosa es más interesante aún de lo que pensaba.

Comment: Estoy esperando hasta esta noche para la validación, pero gracias por toda esta investigación, está muy claro. Pregunta para estafar, tienes la misma imagen que FJSevilla antes. ¿Se conocen?

Comment: ¿No me digas? No tenía ni idea. Soy relativamente nuevo en este foro (empecé a ser activo en enero de 2018) y ya que mi temática más experta es en Python busqué un logo relativo a ese tema. Posteriormente me encontré con excelentes respuestas de @FJSevilla en muchas preguntas que yo estaba a punto de responder, y enseguida reconocí a otro experto, pero no le cononzco personalmente y ni siquiera hemos chateado nunca. Sólo hemos coincidido en comentarios y yo no conocía su anterior logo.

Answer (score 1):

Te comento lo siguiente, con este ejemplo

```
# Hello World program in Python

message = "HELLO WORLD AND HELLO STACK OVER FLOW IN SPANISH"

print(message.isupper())
//Devolverá TRUE

messageTwo = "Hello World of Python"

print(messageTwo.islower())
//Devolverá FALSE
```

1. la variable **`message devuelve en mi ejemplo TRUE por que todos los elementos de la cadena son mayúsculas`** lo cual lo vuelve uan condición cierta
2. la variable **`messageTwo devuelve en mi ejemplo FALSE por que alguno de los elementos de la cadena no cumple la condición de ser minúscula`** con uno solo de los elementos la condición se vuelve **falsa**

*Tercer caso*

Con este ejemplo siguiente te lo explico

```
# Hello World program in Python

messageThree = "Hello World of Python"

print(not messageThree.islower())
//devolverá TRUE
```

> Originalmente la cadena al usar el método islower() debería devolver
>   FALSE por que no todos los caracteres son minúsculas, sin embargo al
>   colocar la negación **not** antes de la instrucción; le estamos
>   indicando que dicha condición no se debe cumplir; es como si estuvieramos  > inviertiendo el comportamiento que dicha función tiene por defecto y ahora > en vez de ser FALSE al no tener todos los elementos en en minúscula,       >  devolverá TRUE

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo de los 3 para ayudarte mas a comprender

https://repl.it/repls/MeanHealthyGenericsoftware

> El operador de negación `not`, a veces también visto como `!` sirve
>   para negar una o varias condiciones que lo precedan; es decir que
>   vayan justo después de dicho operador

Comment: cierto no me di cuenta por escribir rápido @Marine1 gracias